# Powershell array assignment assigns variable, not value?

Tags: arrays, powershell, variable-assignment

I have an example of a program that creates an array, and then attempts to assign the value of that array multiple times into another array as a multidimensional array.

```
$a =@(0,0,0)
$b = @($a,$a,$a)
$b[1][2]=2
$b
'And $a is changed too:'
$a
```

The output is:

```
PS E:\Workarea> .\what.ps1
0
0
2
0
0
2
0
0
2
And $a is changed too:
0
0
2
```

So in this instance, the variable is actually pointing to the original variable.  This is very unexpected behavior.  It's rather neat that one can do this, although I never did use unions that much in my C programming. But I'd like a way to actually just do the assignment of the value, not of the variable.

```
$b = @($a.clone(),$a.clone(),$a.clone())
```

I guess would work, but something tells me that there may be something a little more elegant than that.

Thanks for the input.

This is PowerShell 2.0 under Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign the values of `$a` to `$b` instead of the reference to `$a`, you can wrap the variable in `$()`. Anything in `$()` gets evaluated before using it in the command, so `$($a)` is equivalent to `0, 0, 0`.

```
$a =@(0,0,0)
$b = @($($a),$($a),$($a))
$b[1][2]=2
$b
'$a is not changed.'
$a
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works.

I just don't understand why one instance of $a = $b gives you the value, and another instance gives you the reference.  Especially when there's no guarantee that you're going to get when $b could be anything.

Comment: This is not specific to PowerShell; it is how .NET handles memory allocation for Classes (by reference) vs. Structs (by value). Numerical values (int, double, etc.) are also by value. There is a good explanation at http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx. And from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Be careful in PowerShell ',' is not the enumerator operator, but an array aoperator. The thing you present as multidimensional array is in fact an array of array, you'll find here under the definition of a multidimensional array :

```
$a= new-object ‘object[,]’ 3,3
$a[0,2]=3 
PS > for ($i=0;$i -lt 3;$i++)
>> {
>> for($j=0;$j -lt 3;$j++)
>> {
>> $a[$i,$j]=$i+$j
>> }
>> }
```

Everything work here as `$b` is an array of reference.

Comment: I was trying to use true multidimensional arrays, but they were flipping the bird when I was trying to use them.  Evidently I still have a way to go in learning the ins and outs.  An array of arrays works for what I'm doing, in fact, I was thinking about just using a flat array.

Comment: An array of arrays works for what I'm doing.  From a former C programmer, one dimensional, two dimensional, array of arrays, it's all the same to me.

This still has the problem of assigning it to $b.  It's still by reference.  Using $b = $($a), and then $b[0,2]=3 gives me the Array assignment to [0,2] failed because assignment to slices is not supported. error.

That doesn't happen in my example.

And I hate that enter just adds the comment, and the five minute window for editing sucks.  Just saying.  N00b here.