# Powershell variable declare with CSV object

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell, csv, declare

So I found a strange behavior:
I have an imported CSV file with these titles:

```
$connections | Get-Member
Name                MemberType   Definition
----                ----------   ----------
Equals              Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode         Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType             Method       type GetType()
ToString            Method       string ToString()
Access Method       NoteProperty System.String Access Method=SSH
Accessable          NoteProperty System.String Accessable=N/A
Application         NoteProperty System.String Application=Test
Authentication type NoteProperty System.String Authentication type=rsa
Node                NoteProperty System.String Node=ComputerName
Port                NoteProperty System.String Port=22
User                NoteProperty System.String User=User
```

Now, if I make a new variable from one line

```
$x = $connections[0]
```

Then change something in $x

```
$x.Accessable = $true
```

The change will be visible in $connections[0].

```
$connections[0].Accessable
True
```

Is this a normal behavior? If so how can I make a new variable with a similar object as that line?

Edit:
[Powershell array assignment assigns variable, not value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784487/powershell-array-assignment-assigns-variable-not-value) is about arrays, or multidimensional arrays, this question is about object transfer (copy). The simple answers on that page does not work in this case. Issue still happens.

Comment: Not completely duplicate IMO. Part of question "how to deal with this particular object" not answered there.

Comment: It is a duplicate because it is about copy by reference.  The duplicate has a solution for that.  Although this question also contains an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal behavior, it is how reference types work. You need to make copy of object:

```powershell
$x = $connections[0].PSObject.Copy()
```

Comment: Works OK, one more question thou. How should I implement this, if I would like to use a Where-Object on the $connections object?
Example:
    $x = $connections | Where-Object {$_.Application -eq "Test"}

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to change objects inside Where-Object cmdlet, or you want to just filter them in Where-Object and change them latter?

Comment: Filter, than change later.

Comment: `$connections|Where-Object {...}|ForEach-Object {$_.PSObject.Copy()}`

Comment: @Tumpi So, all you actually need is to make a copy just before you change them.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the noob question. Works great. Yes, I will filter them a lot, first for the Application, if there is one in the parameter, than for the node, than for the user. And some column will have reference, and for that I will replace some things to a new value, but I need the original one, too.